# Javascript: Regex how to match URL anywhere in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Some possible sting like:

```
https://www.google.com
End: https://g.co
Inside https://b.co and https://c.co
```

How to match the URL anywhere in a string?
The URL may at the **end of a string** or end of **space** inside a string.

Currently I'm using the Regex  like:

```
/(https:\/\/.*?)[$|\s]/gi
```

But it seems could not match the URL at the end of a string that the '$' does not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`/(https?:\/\/\S+)/gi`

Or in your way
`/(https:\/\/.*?)($|\s)/ig`

To make things clear, anything inside "[]" already implies  a "|". Adding it in "[]" will result in matching the character "|". Also $ inside the "[]" is considered as the char "$" and not as the end of string because of which your regex doesn't match the URL at the end of text.